# Do Probability and Statistics questions belong here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

When reading random questions on this site, I often come across some Statistics/Probability-related questions. More often than not, these questions receive either not enough or not good enough answers. In other occasions, a good answer eventually comes, but it takes more time than usual in our community.

My question is, then, should we redirect that type of questions to http://stats.stackexchange.com and consider them off the scope of out site? I see some kind of overlap between the two sites at this point, and while it's pretty clear that Statistics and Probability questions are fine for the Stats site, it is more doubtful whether or not they fit here

Answer (score 9):

In general, statistics questions should go to stats.stackexchange.com ... and in general probability questions should go to math.stackexchange.com ... But I think "we" should not redirect them.  If a question is posted in some place, and I think it will do better in another, I suggest that to the poster in a comment.  This leaves it up to that person to re-post it there and delete it here.  Separately, and independently, if a question is inappropriate for this site I vote to close it.  (One of the options we have in math.se when we vote to close is: transfer it to stats.se)